# Refactor Realm migration from linkingObjectsOfClass to RLMLinkingObjects

Tags: ios, realm, realm-migration

Thanks for great work.

Recently we were in deep development process, and we just now moved to realm latest version, from 0.98.1 to 1.0.1.

One of the problems is that we had a migration that looked like this:

```
if (oldSchemaVersion < 2) {
        [migration enumerateObjects:MyClass.className block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {
            newObject[@"property"] = [newObject linkingObjectsOfClass:@"OwnerClass" forProperty:@"myClassInstances"].firstObject;
        }];
}
```

Respectively, `OwnerClass` has this:

```
@property RLMArray<MyClass> *myClassInstances;
```

And `MyClass` has this:

```
@property OwnerClass *instance;
```

So know, as I understand, we should leave the `MyClass` as is, but change `OwnerClass` instead of old to this:
`@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects<MyClass *> *myClassInstances;`.

And after we do this, how the migration block should look?
I really struggled to understand how the new structure should look...
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When declaring a property of type `RLMLinkingObjects` there's no need to include anything related to it in your migration block.